# error using selector as an argument

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm setting up a UINavigationBar and am having trouble with the buttons.  When I do this:

```
-(void)addLeftButton:(NSString *)titl
{
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:titl style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(haikuInstructions)];
self.titleOfNavItem.leftBarButtonItem = button;
}
```

Then everything turns out fine.  But if I do this:

```
-(void)addLeftButton:(NSString *)titl callingMethod:(NSString *)method
{
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:titl style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(method)];
self.titleOfNavItem.leftBarButtonItem = button;
}
```

and call the method in another method like this:

```
[self addLeftButton:@"Instructions" callingMethod:@"haikuInstructions"];
```

I get an `unrecognized selector` error.  Any thoughts about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `NSSelectorFromString(NSString *aSelectorName)`:

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:titl style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:NSSelectorFromString(method)];
```

**EDIT:**
To elaborate, `@selector` directive will treat name between parenthesis literally. What's more, it won't check if that method really exists. This means if you use `@selector(method)` and have also variable `NSString *method = @"haikuInstructions"` you won't point to selector named `"haikuInstructions"`, but to selector named `"method"`.

Comment: @JoelDerfner please read my edited explanation to see what was wrong.